# Intent among three activities error

Tags: android, android-intent

I searched all the question about android intent among three activities in stack overflow, but there were unfortunate without the expect occasion i faced, the first activity which include a simple button but it does't matter and through that activity i pass a data to the second activity, and i want to click the textView(a button) and pass some data to the third activity, the total program is too long and here is the snippet:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.btn_search:
            Intent third = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
            startActivity(third);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

what i expect is that click the button and jump to the third activity, but actually every click it back to the first activity, i am curious if i can not use intent in the second activity?but i think it's ridiculous. Is there any suggestion about this problem.
UPDATE:here is the whole class but there are many empty implementation, and SDK is gaode map, so don't care about the total logic and just pay attention on the onclick event:

```
public class AroundSearchActivity extends Activity implements AMap.OnMapClickListener,
            AMap.OnMarkerClickListener, AMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener, AMap.InfoWindowAdapter,
            View.OnClickListener, PoiSearch.OnPoiSearchListener, LocationSource, AMapLocationListener
    {
        private AMap map;
        private MapView mapView;
        private AMapLocation mapLocation;
        private AMapLocationClient mapLocationClient;
        private AMapLocationClientOption mapLocationClientOption;
        private OnLocationChangedListener locationChangedListener;
        private double latitude;
        private double longitude;
        private double previousLatitude = 0;
        private Marker currentMarker;
        private RelativeLayout detail;
        private TextView name;
        private TextView address;
        private EditText input_text;
        private PoiSearch poiSearch;
        private PoiSearch.Query query;
        private PoiResult result;
        private ArrayList<PoiItem> poiItems;
        private Marker mLastMarker;
        private Marker detailMarker;
        private MyPoiOverlay poiOverlay;
        private String searchStr;
        private int[] showMarkers = {
                R.drawable.poi_marker_1,R.drawable.poi_marker_2,R.drawable.poi_marker_3,R.drawable.poi_marker_4,R.drawable.poi_marker_5,
                R.drawable.poi_marker_6,R.drawable.poi_marker_7,R.drawable.poi_marker_8,R.drawable.poi_marker_9,R.drawable.poi_marker_10,
        };

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.poiaroundsearch_activity);
            mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
            mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            init();
        }
        public void init(){
            if (map == null){
                map = mapView.getMap();
            }
            setUpMap();
            map.setOnMapClickListener(this);
            map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
            map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
            map.setInfoWindowAdapter(this);
            TextView search = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
            search.setOnClickListener(this);
            setup();
        }

        public void setup(){
            detail = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.poi_detail);
            detail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                //toggle detail click event
                Toast.makeText(AroundSearchActivity.this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poi_name);
            address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poi_address);
            input_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_edittext);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            mapView.onResume();
            searchMap();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            mapView.onDestroy();
            deactivate();
        }
        public void setUpMap(){
            map.setLocationSource(this);
            map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            map.setMyLocationType(AMap.LOCATION_TYPE_LOCATE);

        }
        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            locationChangedListener = null;
            if (mapLocationClient != null){
                mapLocationClient.stopLocation();
                mapLocationClient.onDestroy();
            }
            mapLocationClient = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(AMapLocation aMapLocation) {
            if (locationChangedListener != null && aMapLocation != null){
                if(aMapLocation.getErrorCode() == 0){
                    latitude = aMapLocation.getLatitude();

                    longitude = aMapLocation.getLongitude();
                    locationChangedListener.onLocationChanged(aMapLocation);
                    Log.i("CurrentLocation", "latitude is " + latitude + " ,longitude is:" + longitude);//get current latitude and longitude
                    if (currentMarker != null) currentMarker = null;
                    currentMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().
                            position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                            .icon(null)
                            .draggable(true));
                    currentMarker.showInfoWindow();
                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 16));
                   if (previousLatitude == 0){
                        searchMap();
                    }else{
                        String pre = String.valueOf(previousLatitude);
                        String a = pre.substring(pre.indexOf(".") + 1, pre.indexOf(".") + 4);
                        String cur = String.valueOf(latitude);
                        String b = cur.substring(cur.indexOf(".") + 1, cur.indexOf(".") + 4);
                        if (!a.equals(b)){
                            searchMap();
                        }
                    }
                    previousLatitude = latitude;
                }else{
                    int errorCode = aMapLocation.getErrorCode();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "定位失败:"+errorCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void activate(OnLocationChangedListener onLocationChangedListener) {
            locationChangedListener = onLocationChangedListener;
            if (mapLocationClient == null){
                mapLocationClient = new AMapLocationClient(this);
                mapLocationClientOption = new AMapLocationClientOption();
                mapLocationClient.setLocationListener(this);mapLocationClientOption.setLocationMode(AMapLocationClientOption.AMapLocationMode.Hight_Accuracy);
                mapLocationClient.setLocationOption(mapLocationClientOption);
                mapLocationClient.startLocation();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void deactivate() {
            locationChangedListener = null;
            if (mapLocationClient != null){
                mapLocationClient.stopLocation();
                mapLocationClient.onDestroy();
            }
            mapLocationClient = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()){
                case R.id.btn_search:
                    Intent third = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
                    startActivity(third);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            whetherToShowInfo(false);
            if (mLastMarker != null){
                resetLastMarker();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            if (marker.getObject() != null){
                //whether to show the marker detail information
                whetherToShowInfo(true);
                //get the current location
                PoiItem currentItem = (PoiItem) marker.getObject();
                //aim at the next marker and preserve the current marker
                if (mLastMarker == null){
                    mLastMarker = marker;
                }else {
                    resetLastMarker();
                    mLastMarker = marker;
                }
                detailMarker = marker;
                detailMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.poi_marker_pressed));
                setPoiMarkerContent(currentItem);
            }else {
                whetherToShowInfo(false);
                resetLastMarker();
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPoiSearched(PoiResult poiResult, int errorCode) {
            if (errorCode == 1000){
                if (poiResult != null && poiResult.getQuery() != null){
                   if (poiResult.getQuery().equals(query)){//判断是不是同一组查询
                       result = poiResult;//将搜索结果赋值给result
                       poiItems = result.getPois();
                       //列出所有poi搜索结果
                       for (int i = 0; i < poiItems.size(); i++){
                           Log.i("result"+i, poiItems.get(i).getSnippet());
                       }
                       List<SuggestionCity> suggestionCities = result.getSearchSuggestionCitys();
                       if (poiItems != null && poiItems.size() > 0){
                           whetherToShowInfo(false);
                           if (mLastMarker != null) {
                               resetLastMarker();
                           }
                           if (poiOverlay != null){
                               poiOverlay.removeFromMap();
                           }
                           map.clear();
                           poiOverlay = new MyPoiOverlay(this, map, poiItems);
                           poiOverlay.addToMap();
                           poiOverlay.zoomToSpan();//move to the current scene
                                                          map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                           .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.point4))
                           .draggable(false)
                           .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)));
                       }else{
                           if (suggestionCities != null && suggestionCities.size() > 0){
                               showSuggestCity(suggestionCities);
                           }
                       }
                   }
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! No result match your request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }else {
               Log.e("errorInfo", "Search failed:" + errorCode);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPoiItemSearched(PoiItem poiItem, int i) {

        }

        public void whetherToShowInfo(boolean w){
            if (w){
                detail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                detail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        public void resetLastMarker(){
            int index = poiOverlay.getPoiIndex(mLastMarker);
            if (index < 10){
                mLastMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), showMarkers[index])));
            }else{
                mLastMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.marker_other_highlight)));
            }
            mLastMarker = null;
        }

        public void showSuggestCity(List<SuggestionCity> suggestionCities){
            String information = "City information/n";
            for (int i = 0; i < suggestionCities.size(); i++){
                information += "City name" + suggestionCities.get(i).getCityName() +
                        ", City administrative code::" + suggestionCities.get(i).getAdCode();
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, information, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }

        public void searchMap(){
            Toast.makeText(this, searchStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            searchStr = intent.getStringExtra("keyword");
            int currentPage = 0;
            query = new PoiSearch.Query(searchStr.trim(), "", "Beijing");
            query.setPageSize(20);
            query.setPageNum(currentPage);
            LatLonPoint lp = new LatLonPoint(latitude, longitude);
            if (lp != null){
                poiSearch = new PoiSearch(this, query);
                poiSearch.setOnPoiSearchListener(this);
                poiSearch.setBound(new PoiSearch.SearchBound(lp, 2000, true));
                poiSearch.searchPOIAsyn();
            }
        }

        public void setPoiMarkerContent(PoiItem item){
            name.setText(item.getTitle());
            address.setText(item.getSnippet());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post some more code so people can identify any errors and help you accordingly.

Comment: post the manifest and check your logcat for errors/exceptions

Comment: Actually it's a map code with too much line and the concrete error is in the click event, and i have debug for three times and without any conclusion.